# How to display textarea for commentting on each row on clicking a comment link in each row AJAX PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am working on a post and comment system where any user can post "what is on your mind" and have other users reply to his/her post.

The issue i am having is that i want a situation where when a user click on comment link(anchor div), the text area will appear(show, fadein), the user comment and then post(add to database when the comment button is clicked) back to database.

in my code i discover that only the first row can do what i want when i click on the comment link, it show up the textarea for comment, why the other rows contain post, when i try to click on the comment link to display the textarea to input comment, nothing seem to happen.

**SEE SCREEN SHOT OF THE POST/COMMENT SYSTEM**
[image: SEE SCREEN SHOT OF THE POST/COMMENT SYSTEM]

**Bellow is the js code to display the comment textarea**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{


//link to click  action
$('.leavecomment').click(function()
{
var clickedID = this.id; //Split ID string (Split works as PHP explode)
var DbNumberID = clickedID[1]; //and get number from array

$('#leavecomment1'+DbNumberID).fadeIn('slow');
$('#txtcomment').focus(); 

//Textarea without editing.
$(document).mouseup(function()
{
$('#leavecomment1'+DbNumberID).fadeOut('slow');
$('.editpostwrapper').show();
});
});});

</script>
```

**MY HTML/PHP SCRIPT**

```
    <div class="content_wrapper">
<ul id="responds">
<?php
//include db configuration file
include_once("connect/cons.php");

//MySQL query

$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT pagepost.comment,pagepost.regid,pagepost.id,register.id as regid, register.photo,register.lname,register.fname,
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP() -pagepost.date AS CommentTimeSpent FROM pagepost inner join register on pagepost.regid=register.id order by pagepost.id desc");


//get all records from add_delete_record table
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc())
{



  echo '<li id="item_'.$row["id"].'">';

  echo'<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">


    <tr>
    <td width="5%" align="left" valign="top">

    <img  src="profilepics/'.$row['photo'].'" class="photothumbpost">
    </td>
    <td width="0" align="left" valign="top" ><span class="colorpurple">'.  ucwords(strtolower($row['lname'])). " " . ucwords(strtolower($row['fname'])). '</span> </br> <span class="datetimecolor">'.

    date("F j, Y h:i:s A" ,strtotime($row['date'])).'</span>';

$days2 = floor($row['CommentTimeSpent'] / (60 * 60 * 24));
        $remainder = $row['CommentTimeSpent'] % (60 * 60 * 24);
        $hours = floor($remainder / (60 * 60));
        $remainder = $remainder % (60 * 60);
        $minutes = floor($remainder / 60);
        $seconds = $remainder % 60;

if($days2 > 0)
            echo date('F d Y', $row['date']);
            elseif($days2 == 0 && $hours == 0 && $minutes == 0)
            echo "few seconds ago";     
            elseif($days2 == 0 && $hours == 0)
            echo $minutes.' minutes ago';
            else
            echo "few seconds ago"; 



'</td>
<td width="2%" align="right" valign="top">';



    if($row['regid']==$_SESSION['regid'])
    {

    echo '<div class="del_wrapper">
    <!---->
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-left" >

  <span  class="btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" style="background-color:transparent; border:none;background-image:none;">
   <img src="icons/dropdown.png"  title="Options" border="0" />

  </span>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="width:150px; float:left;border:none;" >
   <li style="width:150px; text-align:center;border:none;"><a href="#">Hide this for me</a></li>
  <li style="width:150px; text-align:center;border:none;"> <a href="" class="del_button" id="del-'.$row["id"].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-remove" aria-hidden="true"><font face="Arial">&nbsp;Delete</font></span></a></li>
  <li style="width:150px; text-align:center;border:none;"> <a href="#" class="edit_button" id="post-'.$row["id"].'" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"><font face="Arial">&nbsp;Edit Post</font></span></a></li>

  <li style="width:150px; text-align:center;border:none;"> <a href="#">Like</a></li>
  <li style="width:150px; text-align:center;border:none;"> <a href="#">Unlike</a></li>
  <li class="divider" style="width:150px; text-align:center;"></li>
  <li style="width:150px; text-align:center;border:none;"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#gallery" >Photo Gallery</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!----> 



    </div>';





    }?>
    <?php 

    echo'</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td width="0" align="left" valign="top" colspan="3"><div class="editpostwrapper">'. strip_tags($row['comment']). '</div> 
 <!-- end of edit post wrapper-->

<div class="editpost" style="display:none">
<textarea name="editpost" class="textareapost" cols="45" rows="2" placeholder="Edit Post" title=""></textarea>  
    </div>

<!--like dislike buttons--> 
<a href="#" >Like</a> &nbsp; . <span id="leavecomment1'.$row["id"].'" class="leavecomment">Comment</span> &nbsp; . <a href="#">Share</a>


<!--like dislike buttons--> 

</td>
  </tr>
</table>';


?>

<div id="commentresponds"> 
<?php 
$resultscomment= $mysqli->query("SELECT comment.id,comment.comment,comment.date,comment.pagepostid,pagepost.id,register.fname,register.lname,register.photo from comment 
inner join pagepost on comment.pagepostid=pagepost.id 
inner join register on comment.regid=register.id Where comment.pagepostid='$row[id]' order by comment.id desc");


while($rows = $resultscomment->fetch_assoc())
{

     echo '<span id="item_'.$rows["id"].'"/>';

  echo'<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">

    <tr>
    <td width="5%" align="left" valign="top">

    <img src="profilepics/'.$rows['photo'].'" class="photothumbpost">
    </td>
    <td width="0" align="left" valign="top" ><span class="colorpurple">'.  ucwords(strtolower($rows['lname'])). " " . ucwords(strtolower($rows['fname'])). '</span> </br> <span class="datetimecolor">'.date("F j, Y h:i:s A" ,strtotime($rows['date'])).'</span>
</td>
<td width="2%" align="right" valign="top">

    <div class="del_wrapper"><a href="" class="del_button" id="del-'.$rows["id"].'">
    <img src="icons/dropdown.png"  title="Delete post" border="0" /></a></div>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td width="0" align="left" valign="top" colspan="3">'. $rows['comment']. '

<!--like dislike buttons--> 



<!--like dislike buttons--> 

</td>
  </tr>
</table>';




    //echo'<img src="profilepics/'.$rows['photo'].'" class="photothumbpost">';
//echo $rows['comment']. '<br/>';
}

?>
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="processinsertcomment.php">

    <input type="hidden" name="pagepostid"  id="pagepostid" class="pagepostid" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="regid"  id="regid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['regid'] ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="postcomment"  id="postcomment" value="<?php echo $row['comment'] ?>" />
   <div id="leavecomment1<?php $row["id"] ?>" style="display:none">
    <textarea name="txtcomment" id="txtcomment<?php $row['id']?>" cols="45" rows="2" placeholder="Comment here" title="Your comment here" class="textareacomment"></textarea>
  <br />
  <input type="submit" name="btncomment" id="btncomment" value="Comment"  class="buttonpost" />
<img src="images/ajax.gif" id="LoadingImage" style="display:none" />
</div>
 </form>
<?php
echo'</div>';
echo '</li>';







}

//close db connection
$mysqli->close();



?>
</ul>  

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I have been able to find out the problem with my code,
i was not properly passing the span id of the the class leavecomment, so the click event was not seeing the value assigned to the id, below is the correct dynamic value assigned to the id.

```
<a href="#" >Like</a> &nbsp; . <span id="'.$row["id"].'" class="leavecomment">Comment</span> &nbsp; . <a href="#">Share</a>
```

**THE JQUERY/JS ABOVE INBETWEEN THE HEAD TAG**

```
    $(document).ready(function()
  {


//link to click  action
$('.leavecomment').click(function()
{


 var divname= this.id; //this will automatically represent the value stored in the span id <span id="'.$row["id"].'" class="leavecomment">Comment</span> as seen in the html/php page                  

    $('#leavecomment1'+divname).fadeIn('slow'); 
                $('#txtcomment'+divname).focus();



    });
});

</script>
```

**THE PHP PAGE**

```
    <div class="content_wrapper">
<ul id="responds">
<?php
//include db configuration file
include_once("connect/cons.php");

//MySQL query

$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT pagepost.comment,pagepost.regid,pagepost.id,register.id as regid, register.photo,register.lname,register.fname,
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP() -pagepost.date AS CommentTimeSpent FROM pagepost inner join register on pagepost.regid=register.id order by pagepost.id desc");


//get all records from add_delete_record table
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc())
{




  echo '<li id="item_'.$row["id"].'">';

  echo'<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">


    <tr>
    <td width="5%" align="left" valign="top">

    <img  src="profilepics/'.$row['photo'].'" class="photothumbpost">
    </td>
    <td width="0" align="left" valign="top" ><span class="colorpurple">'.  ucwords(strtolower($row['lname'])). " " . ucwords(strtolower($row['fname'])). '</span> </br> <span class="datetimecolor">'.

    date("F j, Y h:i:s A" ,strtotime($row['date'])).'</span>';

$days2 = floor($row['CommentTimeSpent'] / (60 * 60 * 24));
        $remainder = $row['CommentTimeSpent'] % (60 * 60 * 24);
        $hours = floor($remainder / (60 * 60));
        $remainder = $remainder % (60 * 60);
        $minutes = floor($remainder / 60);
        $seconds = $remainder % 60;

if($days2 > 0)
            echo date('F d Y', $row['date']);
            elseif($days2 == 0 && $hours == 0 && $minutes == 0)
            echo "few seconds ago";     
            elseif($days2 == 0 && $hours == 0)
            echo $minutes.' minutes ago';
            else
            echo "few seconds ago"; 



'</td>
<td width="2%" align="right" valign="top">';





    if($row['regid']==$_SESSION['regid'])
    {

    echo '<div class="del_wrapper">
    <!---->
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-left" >

  <span  class="btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" style="background-color:transparent; border:none;background-image:none;">
   <img src="icons/dropdown.png"  title="Options" border="0" />

  </span>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="width:150px; float:left;border:none;" >
   <li style="width:150px; text-align:center;border:none;"><a href="#">Hide this for me</a></li>
  <li style="width:150px; text-align:center;border:none;"> <a href="" class="del_button" id="del-'.$row["id"].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-remove" aria-hidden="true"><font face="Arial">&nbsp;Delete</font></span></a></li>
  <li style="width:150px; text-align:center;border:none;"> <a href="#" class="edit_button" id="post-'.$row["id"].'" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"><font face="Arial">&nbsp;Edit Post</font></span></a></li>

  <li style="width:150px; text-align:center;border:none;"> <a href="#">Like</a></li>
  <li style="width:150px; text-align:center;border:none;"> <a href="#">Unlike</a></li>
  <li class="divider" style="width:150px; text-align:center;"></li>
  <li style="width:150px; text-align:center;border:none;"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#gallery" >Photo Gallery</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!----> 



    </div>';





    }?>
    <?php 

    echo'</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td width="0" align="left" valign="top" colspan="3"><div class="editpostwrapper">'. strip_tags($row['comment']). '</div> 
 <!-- end of edit post wrapper-->

<div class="editpost" style="display:none">
<textarea name="editpost" class="textareapost" cols="45" rows="2" placeholder="Edit Post" title=""></textarea>  
    </div>

**<!--THIS IS THE LINK TO CLICK,HERE WE HAVE LIKE,**COMMENT**, SHARE,-->**  

<a href="#" >Like</a> &nbsp; . <span id="'.$row["id"].'" class="leavecomment">Comment</span> &nbsp; . <a href="#">Share</a>


**<!--THIS IS THE END LINK TO CLICK,HERE WE HAVE LIKE,**COMMENT**, SHARE,-->**  

</td>
  </tr>
</table>';


?>

<div id="commentresponds"> 
<?php 
$resultscomment= $mysqli->query("SELECT comment.id,comment.comment,comment.date,comment.pagepostid,pagepost.id,register.fname,register.lname,register.photo from comment 
inner join pagepost on comment.pagepostid=pagepost.id 
inner join register on comment.regid=register.id Where comment.pagepostid='$row[id]' order by comment.id desc");


while($rows = $resultscomment->fetch_assoc())
{

     echo '<span id="item_'.$rows["id"].'"/>';

  echo'<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">

    <tr>
    <td width="5%" align="left" valign="top">

    <img src="profilepics/'.$rows['photo'].'" class="photothumbpost">
    </td>
    <td width="0" align="left" valign="top" ><span class="colorpurple">'.  ucwords(strtolower($rows['lname'])). " " . ucwords(strtolower($rows['fname'])). '</span> </br> <span class="datetimecolor">'.date("F j, Y h:i:s A" ,strtotime($rows['date'])).'</span>
</td>
<td width="2%" align="right" valign="top">

    <div class="del_wrapper"><a href="" class="del_button" id="del-'.$rows["id"].'">
    <img src="icons/dropdown.png"  title="Delete post" border="0" /></a></div>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td width="0" align="left" valign="top" colspan="3">'. $rows['comment']. '

<!--like dislike buttons--> 



<!--like dislike buttons--> 

</td>
  </tr>
</table>';


    //THIS IS THE MAJOR FOCUS DISPLAYING THE COMMENT ON CLICKING THE COMMENT LABEL AS SEEN ABOVE
}

?>
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="processinsertcomment.php">

    <input type="hidden" name="pagepostid"  id="pagepostid" class="pagepostid" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="regid"  id="regid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['regid'] ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="postcomment"  id="postcomment" value="<?php echo $row['comment'] ?>" />
   <div id="leavecomment1<?php echo $row["id"] ?>" class="leavecomment1<?php echo $row["id"] ?>" style="display:none" >
    <textarea name="txtcomment" id="txtcomment<?php echo $row['id']?>" cols="45" rows="2" placeholder="Comment here" title="Your comment here" class="textareacomment"></textarea>
  <br />
  <input type="submit" name="btncomment" id="btncomment" value="Comment"  class="buttonpost" />
<img src="images/ajax.gif" id="LoadingImage" style="display:none" />
</div>
 </form>
<?php
echo'</div>';
echo '</li>';







}

//close db connection
$mysqli->close();



?>
</ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because in HTML you have multiple textareas with same `id` attribute that is `txtcomment`.
You should try giving each textarea, comments anchor tag a unique id.

use `id="txtComment.'.$row["id"].'"` and `id="leavecomment.'.$row["id"].'"`

> NOTE: when an HTML page have multiple DOM element with same `id`, it
>   will traverse through the last one and return the last occurrence of
>   element.

Comment: as you can see i have all the unique id attach to the div, do help check the js code to see if you can figure out something i have not done right